# Google Colab outputs disappears right after is shown

Tags: python, colab

I haven't been able to solve this problem. From a few days ago my colab notebooks outputs are malfunctioning: the outputs appear after the execution of the cell but dissapear inmediately. If I click on the fullscreen output I can see it, but it's very counterproductive to work that way. Anybody knows what is happening? [image: Problem]